# Gradle build failed to resolve aar library dependency (trnql sdk)

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I attempt to build my project using gradle, I get the following error:

```
Failed to resolve: com.trnql:lib-release 1.0.0
```

It seems it cannot find the android archive file (aar) that is in the libs folder. The dependencies section of the build.gradle file looks like this:

[image]

And the project structure looks like this:

[image]

The aar file is valid, it is just not resolved by the build system. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: can you please inform the version of android studio you are using? that would be helpful...

Comment: these instructions work for both android studio and intellij idea

Answer (score 47):

The problem here is that gradle will try to find this aar in one of the declared repository. The libs directory is not a repository... BUT you can declare it like this :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

and gradle will find it.

Comment: I already have this code in the build.gradle file. My fault, should have shared the whole file :)

Comment: I had forgotten to add these lines. Silly me.

Answer (score 18):

When you create a new Android studio project, your top level build.gradle will have a buildscript and an allproject part (see below), and if you insert the

```
flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
```

part into the buildscript's repositories, it won't work.
You have to paste it into the allprojects' repositories, like here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

put your aar file in libs dir, then modify part of your build.gradle file like below, the difference is that you missed *.aar when compile fileTree

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

compile fileTree(dir:'libs', include:['*.jar', '*.aar'])
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, in my library module my build.gradle looked something like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs "libs"
        }
    }
}
```

I had to remove the `buildscript` bit so that it looked like this in the end:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "libs"
    }
}
```

Then it was able to sync and, thereafter, build.

Answer (score 4):

And to be complete as possible:  Lets say you want your AAR's in another directory in a sub-module....

Then in your TOP LEVEL project's build.gradle file, you would do the following:

```
buildscript {
    // stuff here
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // all your standard  stuff, jcenter, maven, etc
        flatDir {
            dirs project(':MY_MODULE_NAME').file('MODULE_SUB_DIRECTORY')
        }
    }
}
```

If your module directory layout looked like this:

```
MyFancyModule/
  /aars         <-- aar files go here
  /build
  /libs         <-- jar files go here
  /src
  build.gradle   <-- this is NOT your top level gradle file
```

Then the line in your TOP LEVEL GRADLE FILE would look like:

```
dirs project(':MyFancyModule').file('aars')
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for being specific. Many answers don't accurately describe where to update your gradle and paths